# Is this classifier better than a random guess?

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I'm working with the [SAMHSA Mental Health Client-Level Dataset](https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/dataset/mental-health-client-level-data-2021-mh-cld-2021-ds0001). I'm trying to train classifiers to predict the disorder given the rest of the columns. There are 14 binary disorder columns (bipolar, schizophrenia, ADHD, etc.) based on diagnoses.

The outputs are 14d 0/1 vectors. This can be viewed as a multiclass problem with 2^14 = 16384 classes (only ~432 actually occurring, and fewer if binned), or a multilabel problem. See [discussion on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641927/how-to-encode-multiple-boolean-targets-for-logistic-regression).

If I treat this as a multiclass problem with all the classes, there is a distribution of the multi-disorders:

```
label         
00000001000000    16041
00000000001000    11307
00010000000000     7543
01000000000000     7457
00000010000000     5639
00100000000000     5422
00100001000000     5407
00000000000001     4166
10000000001000     2701
10000001000000     2467
```

where

```
disorder_cols = ['SUB','TRAUSTREFLG','ANXIETYFLG','ADHDFLG','CONDUCTFLG','DELIRDEMFLG','BIPOLARFLG','DEPRESSFLG','ODDFLG','PDDFLG','SCHIZOFLG','PERSONFLG','ALCSUBFLG','OTHERDISFLG']
```

[image: confusion matrix random forest]

With a train:test split of 80:20 with 100_000 samples, using RandomForestClassifier on the full 16384 classes, I obtain:

```
accuracy: 0.25895
precision: 0.18098683418841843
recall: 0.25895
```

Using multiclass LogisticRegression,

```
accuracy: 0.2883
precision: 0.17213465356962485
recall: 0.2883
```

If I just guess the majority class, that's 16041/100_000 = 16.041% accuracy. Can I conclude that my models are better than just guessing the majority class?

How should I calculate accuracy with the imbalanced classes?

Code: https://github.com/jacksonwalters/ml-examples/tree/main/mental_health_client-level_data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I have edited the question. The edit resolves the issue.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what the question is, because some of the approaches you've tried dramatically change what the question being solved is, and the metrics are incomparable.  How do you want to use the model(s)?

Comment: @BenReiniger We had a pretty thorough discussion at CV: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641927/how-to-encode-multiple-boolean-targets-for-logistic-regression. It’s possible to just discuss the three cases mentioned, and the pros and cons of each. As stated  in the question, you can treat it as a multiclass problem with 15 classes, 13 classes, or 8192 classes. However, it’s better to treat it as a multilabel problem, with 13 probably correlated Boolean targets. The model is just a classification model, predicting diagnostic classes from the other columns (demographic data).

Comment: I’m closing this question because its [cross-post to stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/641927/232706) had an accepted answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I've consolidated the threads of inquiry into just using two multiclass classification models (RandomForest and LogisticRegression). I'm now just trying to figure out which accuracy metric to use.